# Google Place get Share Link Maps by Place ID

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-urls

I would like to get place maps link by place id 
ex [Maps Place Link](https://www.google.co.id/maps/place/The+Ritz-Carlton+Jakarta,+Mega+Kuningan/@-6.2285344,106.8249858,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x2e69f3e522c0267f:0x3f73c979c108fbf2!8m2!3d-6.2285397!4d106.8271745?hl=en)

I have this place ID **ChIJfybAIuXzaS4R8vsIwXnJcz8** and also coordinate long **106.8271745** and lat **-6.2285397**

Q: How to generate share link like above? I try to generate manually with string name and long lat then put it in google maps place url but it is not correct sometime

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended by Google and most straight forward way is using the Google Maps URLs API. You can read about this API here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#search-action

Using the Google Maps URLs you can create the following link for your place:

`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=106.8271745%2C-6.2285397&query_place_id=ChIJfybAIuXzaS4R8vsIwXnJcz8`

The result will be as shown in my screenshot

[image]

I hope this helps!